# Need to some cells to be editable in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to populate the data from the `gridview` .My gridview looks like

```
Title  Year  Item

ABC    2014   A

MNC    2013   B

XYZ    2014   Q
```

In this `gridview` the last 2 rows should be editable.How will I do it in an optimized way?

Comment: Where is your code? I don't see it maybe it's ninja code

Answer (score 0):

You can go over the KeyDown event handler and use the RowIndex property of current cell with Rows Count property:

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab && dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex > dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
    }
}
```